# Programs affected by python version update coming with new ubuntu distribution

Tags: package-management, python, odoo

We were running odoo 9 under ubuntu 16.04 with no problem. We decided to move recently to ubuntu 18.04 but when installing odoo 9 under such ubuntu version We are running into lots of trouble. Reason behind seems to be that python version for ubuntu 18.04 is different that the one of ubuntu 16.04 and thus some packages (namely python-imaging, python-pybabel and python-pypdf) seem to be missing. Possible solutions I come up with (maybe stupid ones, feel free to point it out since I am not an expert on this matters):

1. Get somewhere, somehow the python-imaging, python-pybabel and
   python-pypdf for version 18.04. (If this makes sense:where and how
   please)
2. Have odoo some how use an older python version while the
   rest of the system uses the newest (Possible? if so,how could be
   achieved?)
3. Uninstall current python version and install the one of
   16.04 (Makes sense or is this a nightmare due to dependencies? If so, how to accomplish it?)

Restrictions: Maintaining version 9 for odoo is a must in our company, answer should not be too cryptic since I am neither a python nor ubuntu expert.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: maybe the missing packages can be installed with `pip` ?

Comment: Current version odoo 11  seems to work well with Ubuntu 18.04.  Or you can use the [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo/).

Comment: Regarding point 2, you could research using a virtualenv.

Comment: Regarding point 3, `python3` must be Python 3.6.5. Don't change it. But `python2` is not required, so you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I tried pip, and either not working or I am not skilled enough... I will check the docker image solution and try to figure out how to do since I have never worked with those before (thanks for the hint). What is a virtualenv? Sorry I need Sesame street like kind of answers since I am not so skilled in IT issues. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it. Maybe is dirty and ugly (maybe not) and I hope the place I got the packages from is safe... Actually I found that the 3 missing packages are available in https://www.ubuntuupdates.org under packages (I downloaded and installed the 3 packages corresponding for the Xenial Xerus (ubuntu 16.04) since given that they are not available under the Bionic Beaver (ubuntu 18.04) I do not expect python 3 to be calling the wrong package. So  far it seems to work fine (odoo 9 server up and running as wanted). For python experts maybe this is dirty and ugly as stated, but at least seems to be a work around for not so skilled IT people as myself.